# Error enabling SSL while installing cassandra(DataStax Community Edition)on Windows

Tags: ssl, openssl, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

My System : Windows 7 64-bit. While instaling Datastax Community Edition of cassandra,

As mentioned in the Prerequisites here :
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/gettingstarted/index.html#getting_started/gettingStartedWindows_t.html

I tried enabling SSL using instructions given here
http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/configure/configure_ssl#config-ssl-win

but below is the error I get.

```
C:\>python "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\bin\setup.py"
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\opscenter\bin\setup.py", line 51
    print "Error when creating opscenter SSL files. Error was:\n"
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: @Yvette : but I din't change anything after the download of Datastax Community Edition of Cassandra....

Comment: @Yvette : I have already tried that twice. Same problem still continues to occur.

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Answer (score 1):

What version of openssl did you install? That error is indicating the openssl command complained about a syntax error. OpsCenter specifically requires openssl 0.9.8 on windows.

http://www.datastax.com/docs/opscenter/configure/configure_ssl#enabling-ssl-windows

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file **create-file-pair.bat** and set the variable **OPENSSL_EXE** to the path where your installation of OpenSSL is.